# Intersecting non-empty arrays

Tags: ruby

I have three arrays I want to intersect, but I want to ignore the ones that are empty.

This code seems too verbose. Is there a more efficient approach?

```
if a.empty? && b.empty?
  abc = c
elsif a.empty? && c.empty?
  abc = b
elsif b.empty? && c.empty?
  abc = a
elsif a.empty?
  abc = b & c
elsif b.empty?
  abc = a & c
elsif c.empty?
  abc = a & b
else
  abc = a & b & c
end
```

Comment: those s's are c's? are they arrays?

Comment: I assumed so and edited. I also assumed that `a`, `b` and `c` are arrays that may or may not me empty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about

```
abc = [a,b,c].reject(&:empty?).reduce(:&)
```

The first part, `[a,b,c]` puts your arrays in an array. The second bit with [`reject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reject) runs `empty?` on every element and rejects it if the result is true, returning an array of arrays where the empty arrays are removed. The last part, [`reduce`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) runs the equivalent of your `a & b & c` but since we discarded all empty arrays in the previous step, you don't end up with an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party...

```
a = [1,3,4,5]
b = []
c = [2,3,5,6]

t = a | b | c # => [1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6]
[a,b,c].map {|e| e.empty? ? t : e}.reduce(:&) # => [3, 5]
```